# How do I use grunt config's template strings?

Tags: gruntjs

I setup the template at the top of `module.exports` in my gruntfile:

```
// Self calling so we get a value.
// Expects only a single schema in the schema folder.
grunt.config.set('schemaPath', function() {
    console.log(grunt.file.expand('schema/*.json')[0]);
    return grunt.file.expand('schema/*.json')[0];
}());

console.log(grunt.config.get('schemaPath'));
```

Later on, when configuring a command, I want to use the template string like so:

```
stripJsonComments: {
  currentSchema: {
    files: {
      'build/<%= schemaPath %>': '<%= schemaPath %>'
    }
  }
}
```

However I get an error: `An error occurred while processing a template (Cannot read property 'src' of undefined).`  After investigating it seems that the template strings are not expanded and instead just dropped.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use templates as property names, they won't get processed. So `'build/<%= schemaPath %>': '<%= schemaPath %>'` won't work.

I suggest looking into another variant of [task configuration](http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#files), where you define your `src` and `dest` properties explicitly and then use templates of values.
If you're looking for multiple src-dest file mappings you can use the [files array format](http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#files-array-format). It would look something like this:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

  grunt.initConfig({
    concat: {
      main: {
        files: [
          {src: ['<%= file1 %>', '<%= file2 %>'], dest: '<%= destPath %>'},
        ]
      },
    }    
  });


  grunt.config.set('file1', 'foo.js');
  grunt.config.set('file2', 'bar.js');
  grunt.config.set('destPath', 'dest/baz.js');

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat');

  grunt.registerTask('default', ['concat']);

};
```